# Unity - insert video for android deployment

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm creating augmented reality app that plays video for android using unity(personal version)
*Movie texture*      is not for android script. 
What do I need to do to insert the video into Unity and deploy it for android.

Comment: I believe that you have 2 choices: Use device's camera or use the Unity pro feature.

Comment: Except for Unity pro feature. What do you mean when you said "Use device's camera"?

Comment: You could create a plugin to capture video for Android using Java... Is quite tedious process but can solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for the information CABRRA.